# docker - local DNS

Tags: docker, dns

I am trying to run Ubuntu inside of Docker, but my network has several restrictions:

1. must use network's DNS, when I set it, I do not get a response, I suspect it is because the return address is the docker IP 172 ...
2. must use network's Proxy, I can set an env, but it is useless without DNS working

I am trying this:

```
docker run --dns=10.69.114.61 -it ubuntu
docker run --dns=172.17.0.1 -it ubuntu (docker0 interface IP)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers will use docker host's dns settings by default. 
In order to specify DNS server:

```
docker run --dns=10.69.114.61 -it debian:jessie /bin/bash
root@299849f13f21:/# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 10.69.114.61
```

Needless to say you must supply your network's DNS server IP address to the `--dns` flag.

```
docker run --dns=<your DNS server IP> -it debian:jessie /bin/bash
```

As you pointed out you should specify `HTTP_PROXY` variable to use your proxy server.

Comment: By default, it appears docker or the ubuntu image I'm using is using Google's DNS.  When I changed that, it appears my firewall is blocking the requests from even reaching the DNS server because the IP address in the return address is 172 ... nonroutable.  Let's say I'm letting my requests go out to 8.8.8.8 and the return address is 172 ... How does that return?  What my router would do with NAT is handle that for me.  Why isn't docker doing that?

Comment: Your Internet edge router/firewall, will use NAT and translate that address to a public ip address so thats no problem.

Comment: Okay, so my workstation then needs to be setup to properly forward connections.  I think I need to setup an iptables rule (to enable forwarding) and quite possibly set a kernel configuration to enable ip forwarding?

Comment: Can you ping 8.8.8.8 on your workstation? if so you dont need to do anything, Also try pinging 8.8.8.8  inside the container.

Comment: Okay, I used the debian:jessie container as it had the ping command :).  I can ping my workstation IP, but not the network router/gateway.  On the router/gateway, I see the ping is hitting the rplog filter (the IP address listed is 172.17.0.2).

Comment: Thats weired, You should see your workstation ip, How did you install docker, Did you mess with iptables rules? if so, stop docker service, do `iptables -F` to flush all the rules then start the docker service , start the container and try again.

Comment: I have to figure out how to get it sorted out with shorewall, my iptables wrapper ...  With shorewall disabled, I can get to the gateway okay after restarting docker.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135985/discussion-between-farhad-farahi-and-walter-white).